# New Date from ISO-8601 throws 'Invalid Date'

Tags: javascript, date, safari, iso8601

I have two dates both in a valid ISO-8601 format and I'm trying to convert them to a Date object.

```js
console.log(new Date('2019-08-03T18:17:28.119Z'));
console.log(new Date('2019-05-09T08:25:22+0000'));
```

```
Output1: Sat Aug 03 2019 20:17:28 GMT+0200 (CEST)
Output2: Invalid Date
```

How come JavaScript doesn't recognize the second date as a valid ISO-8601 format?

How can I create a Date object out of that format?

Comment: what JS engine? both works in node 8 and a recent chrome.

Comment: I am getting a valid date on Chrome 75, what's your browser ?

Comment: Works for me in Firefox amigo

Comment: Safari 12.1.2. I will try in Chrome now

Comment: Chrome works. Seems like this is a Safari issue.

Comment: "+0000" should be "+00:00".

Comment: Quick fix if you can't change the input format: `var d = '2019-05-09T08:25:22+0000'; d = d.substring(0, 22) + ':' + d.substring(22);`

Comment: not sure if this is valid or not 2019-05-09T08:25:22+0000, 
but when timezone is 0 UTC offset, the 2019-05-09T08:25:22Z is valid.

Answer (score 0):

ECMA-262 requires that anything that doesn't conform to [its version of ISO 8601](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-date-time-string-format) is implementation dependent. Formats that are close but not precise are likely to result in an invalid date in at least some browsers. Others may be more tolerant.

In this case, the offset "+0000" should be "+00:00". Similarly, replacing the "T" with a space may result in an invalid date, or not, depending on the implementation.

```js
// Invalid date maybe
console.log(new Date('2019-05-09T08:25:22+0000').toString());

// valid
console.log(new Date('2019-05-09T08:25:22+00:00').toString());
```

To parse the problematic format, either add the missing colon before parsing, or (preferably) either write your own parse function (not difficult) or use a library (there are many good ones to chose from).

Also see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)